# Can expose Rabbitmq on internet?

Tags: rabbitmq

I want to use rabbitmq in a project, some clients have to comunicate with the rabbitmq server over internet
What is the best way to expose rabbitmq on the Internet ? 
should i use a http gateway or directly expose the rabbitmq port ?

Guillaume.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can, it is what https://www.cloudamqp.com/ does.

You need to implement the same security policies you'd use for a web site.

For example, put a load-balancer in front of your rabbitmq cluster, use the [SSL connections](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html), you could also configure your firewall to accept the connections only from specific ip addresses etc etc..